# Windows Powershell to replace a set of characters from a text files in a folder

Tags: powershell

Working on a code which will replace a set of characters from a text files in a folder.  IS there a way where it can do it for all the files in the folder.  I am using a Windows 7 OS and Powershell Version 3.Attaching the code which I have. The issue is it creates a new file when I run the code  (New_NOV_1995.txt) but it doesn't change any character in the new file as mentioned in the code. Help very much Appreciated.

```
    $lookupTable = @{
'¿' = '|' 
'Ù' = '|' 
'À' = '|' 
'Ú' = '|' 
'³' = '|' 
'Ä' = '-'
}

$original_file = 'C:\FilePath\NOV_1995.txt'
$destination_file =  'C:\FilePath\NOV_1995_NEW.txt'

Get-Content -Path $original_file | ForEach-Object { 
    $line = $_

    $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        if ($line -match $_.Key)
        {
            $line = $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
        }
    }
   $line
} | Set-Content -Path $destination_file
```

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem` in your first line instead of `Get-Content`.

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, I'm assuming that H:\Replace_String is a directory.  In your code above, you don't have a backslash so it would only select files in the root of H:.

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem -path H:\Replace_String\*.txt
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Cat", "New_Cat" } |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Dog", "New_Dog" } |
    Set-Content $file
}
```

Comment: Thx Tony...This code is giving error :Positional parameter cannot be found for path.

Comment: It works for me--the only thing different is I used C: instead of H:.  I am running PowerShell 4.0, so if you are running something older that may make a difference.  I Google "Positional parameter cannot be found for path" and it comes up with zero hits.  Did you include the complete error message?  You might try putting quotes around H:\Replace_String\*.txt but I don't know what else to try off the top of my head.

Comment: "A Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'path' at H:\Replace_string\<Program_name>.ps1..+ $ ConfigFiles = Get-content - path <H:\xxxx.\*.txt                                                                       I am using PS Version 3

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem`, not `Get-Content`.

Comment: ...and it needs to be `-path` not `- path`.  Please copy and paste the code in my answer and run it without modifications.  Once you have something that works, then you can modify it as needed.

Comment: @HarryPuttar The positional parameter error is most likely because you are running this in ISE and you need the curly brace one space after your parens -- so "foreach($file in $configFiles) {" then a line break.

Answer (score 1):

The (original) answer proposed by Tony Hinkle needs another loop.  The reason for this is that `Get-Content` produces an array.  Each line represents an element of the array.

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem -path 'H:\Replace_String\*.txt'

foreach ($file in $configFiles){
    $output = @()
    $content = Get-Content $file

    foreach ($line in $content) {
        $line = $content.Replace("Cat", "New_Cat")
        $line = $content.Replace("Dog", "New_Dog")

        $output += $line

    }

    $output | Set-Content -Path $file 
}
```

Edit:  I noticed that Tony Hinkle's answer was modified as I posted this.  He's sending everything through a pipeline where I'm storing the array in a variable then looping through.  The pipeline method is probably more memory efficient.  The variable with second loop for each element of the array is more easily modified to do more than just the two replacments.