# Replacing bunch of string characters in a text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-3.0

Working on a PowerShell code which will replace a set of characters from a text file in a folder (Contain lot of Text files). Is there a way where it can do it for all the files in the folder?

The issue is it creates a new file when I run the code (New_NOV_1995.txt) but it doesn't change any characters in the new file.

```
 $lookupTable = @{
'¿' = '|' 
'Ù' = '|' 
'À' = '|' 
'Ú' = '|' 
'³' = '|' 
'Ä' = '-'
}

$original_file = 'C:\FilePath\NOV_1995.txt'
$destination_file =  'C:\FilePath\NOV_1995_NEW.txt'

Get-Content -Path $original_file | ForEach-Object { 
    $line = $_

    $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        if ($line -match $_.Key)
        {
            $line = $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
        }
    }
   $line
} | Set-Content -Path $destination_file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Powershell to replace a set of characters from a text files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509221/windows-powershell-to-replace-a-set-of-characters-from-a-text-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: The Special characters mentioned ('¿', 'Ù', 'À','Ú','³','Ä')  occur multiple times  in a text file.

Comment: Aside from that I would like to improve your replacement logic. Also are your files very large?

Answer (score 0):

While something like this would work, performance might be a problem. My only testing was on a tiny file containing the `$lookupTable`.

```
 $lookupTable = @{
'¿' = '|' 
'Ù' = '|' 
'À' = '|' 
'Ú' = '|' 
'³' = '|' 
'Ä' = '-'
}

$original_file = 'C:\FilePath\NOV_1995.txt'
$destination_file =  'C:\FilePath\NOV_1995_NEW.txt'

$originalContent = Get-Content -Path $original_file
$lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | % {
   $originalContent = $originalContent -replace $_.Key,$_.Value
}
$originalContent | Out-File -FilePath $destination_file
```

Comment: Did it work for you.?....For me it''s not changing the special chars. Just copies and pastes the same old file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as you have it there is actually working for me. There is still a possible encoding issue maybe with *your* files. Does your file look right when you just read it into the console with `Get-Content $path`? If the file does not look right you might need to play with the `-Encoding` switches of the 
`Set-Content` and `Get-Content`cmdlets.

---

Improving on your current logic.

I changed your `$lookuptable` to a pair of psobjects. Since you are making the same replacement for the most part I combined them into a single regex.

The next part I hummed and hawed about but since, after my proposed change, you are only doing two replacements I figure you could just chain the two into a single replacement line. Otherwise you could have a foreach-object in there but I think this is simpler and faster.

This way we don't need to test for a match. `-replace` is doing the testing for us.

```
$toPipe = [pscustomobject]@{
    Pattern = '¿|Ù|À|Ú|³'
    Replacement = "|"
}
$toHypen =  [pscustomobject]@{
    Pattern = 'Ä'
    Replacement = "-"
}

$path = "c:\temp\test\test"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path | ForEach-Object{
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace $toPipe.Pattern,$toPipe.Replacement -replace $toHypen.Pattern,$toHypen.Replacement | 
            Set-Content $_.FullName 
}
```

Note that this will change the original files. Testing is encouraged.

`Set-Content` and `Get-Content` are not the best when it comes to performance so you might need to consider using `[IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file)` and its partner static method `[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file)`

Comment: I thought there was an encoding issue but testing shows me I am possibly mistaken.